# Bootstrap 3 navbar colour dropdown button when active

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a bootstrap Navbar that I want to colour. The dropdown only displays when the button on the navbar is clicked, rather than hovered over, so it is suitable for mobile users.

Right now it appears white and the text colour changes black when the button is active. When it is hovered over, it changes to a darker shade of blue and this is the shade of blue I want it to stay when it is active. I've tried many other examples such as .active > a:focus and .active > a:active, but neither work.

The html code for the navbar is below:

```
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default">

            <div class="container-fluid" id="fullNav">

                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarBody" aria-expanded="false" id="collapsedNavbarExpand">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logo</a>

                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarBody">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li class="dropdown">

                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navOption" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Tourism 
                                <span class="caret"> </span>

                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                <li> <a href="../Pages/tourismHub.html"> <b> Tourism Hub </b> </a> </li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/eatingOut.html"> Eating Out </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/attractions.html"> Attractions </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/events.html"> Events </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/history.html"> Town History </a> </li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">

                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navOption" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                                Residents
                                <span class="caret"> </span>

                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                <li> <a href="../Pages/residentsHub.html"> <b> Residents Hub </b> </a> </li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/events.html"> Events </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/eatingOut.html"> Eating Out </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/history.html"> History </a> </li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">

                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navOption" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                                Prospective Residents
                                <span class="caret"> </span>

                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                <li> <a href="../Pages/prospectiveResidentsHub.html"> <b> Prospective Residents Hub </b> </a> </li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/realEstate.html"> Real Estate </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/attractions.html"> Attractions </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/history.html"> Town History </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/eatingOut.html"> Eating Out </a> </li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">

                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navOption" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                                Locations
                                <span class="caret"> </span>

                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                <li> <a href="../Pages/locationsHub.html"> <b> Locations Hub </b> </a> </li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/marina.html"> Marina </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/highStreet.html"> High Street </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/parishWharf.html"> Parish Wharf </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="../Pages/lakeGrounds.html"> Lake Grounds </a> </li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                        <li> <a href="../Pages/map.html" class="navOption"> Map </a> </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>

        </nav>
```

The indentation is a bit broken due to pasting it out of my website. The CSS code can be seen in JSFiddle. bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css and jquery-2.2.0.js are imported further up the page.

A working JSFiddle example is linked below. To see the effect in action you must expand the result window so the navbar is not collapsed. You must also remove your mouse from one of the dropdown buttons once clicked to see it turn white.

Here is the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/hezejk88/9/

Any solutions would be great thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That style is applied when the dropdown is both `.open` *and* the `a` element is focussed:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #555;
}
```

Your current override doesn't cater for the focussed style, so you simply need to add that in:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, /* <- This one was missing. */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #084c78;
}
```

[**Amended JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/hezejk88/10/). The fix is applied at line 53.

Comment: Ah since you explained it better i deleted my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this js.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = document.URL;
    $(".list-unstyled li").each(function () {
        var y = $(this).children("a").attr('href');
        var pieces = url.split('/');
        //var routeData= route.substring(0, route.indexOf('?'));
        var abc= pieces[pieces.length - 1].substring(0,pieces[pieces.length - 1].indexOf('?'));
        if(abc)
        {
            if (pieces[pieces.length - 1].substring(0,pieces[pieces.length - 1].indexOf('?')) == y) 
            {
                if ($(this).parents(".has-submenu").length == 1) 
                {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(this).parents(".has-submenu").addClass("active")
                }
                else 
                {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (pieces[pieces.length - 1] == y) 
            {
                if ($(this).parents(".has-submenu").length == 1) 
                {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(this).parents(".has-submenu").addClass("active")
                }
                else 
                {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: When $(this).addClass("active"); you can create css and add in place addClass("active"); this

Comment: Dude srsly this can be done with 1 line of code in css

Comment: ok no problem  this code for current menu active or drop down menu active check and active with css